# How to run a snort rule over pcap file

Tags: snort, packet

I have a `pcap` file, and what I wanted to know is how can I apply the `Snort`rule below which I've already written within the rules folder in my log folder:

```
alert icmp any any -> any any (msg:"TCP Packet"; sid:477; rev:3;)
```

How can I execute this rule over the pcap file I have?

Answer (score 7):

Supposing the rule is already in a Snort `.rules` file and `snort.conf` is configured to include the `.rules` with the rule to test...

```
$ snort -r foo.pcap
```

...or...

```
$ snort --pcap-single=foo.pcap
```

...from...

http://manual.snort.org/node8.html

Comment: So don't i need to mention the rules file in the command? I tried this command it worked: `snort -r cap.pcap -c rulefile.rules`

Comment: @Kulasangar: The `-c` is used to specify the config file (`snort.conf`) to use; the config needs to specify the `.rules` to include (`include your.rules`).

Comment: The pcaps must be saved as "modified tcpdump" or you will get the error `can't initialize daq pcap (-1)`